# Convert a nested hierarchical array into flattened object

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, flatten

I have a nested json array object which looks like below

```
var inputData = [
  {
    "id": "P1",
    "parentTopicId": null,
    "title": "demo title 1",
    "children": [
      {
        "id": "P1-Child1",
        "parentTopicId": "P1",
        "title": "demo title a",
        "children": [
          {
            "id": "id1.1",
            "parentTopicId": "P1Child1",
            "title": "some demo title b",
            "children": [
              {
                "id": "id1.1.1",
                "parentTopicId": "id1.1",
                "title": "demo title",
                "children": []
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": "P1-Child2",
        "parentTopicId": "P1",
        "title": "some title 2",
        "children": [
          {
            "id": "id1.2",
            "parentTopicId": "P1-Child2",
            "title": "demo titlename",
            "children": []
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "P2",
    "parentTopicId": null,
    "title": "Example Title B",
    "children": [
      {
        "id": "P2-Child1",
        "parentTopicId": "P2",
        "title": "example title b2",
        "children": [
          {
            "id": "id2.1",
            "parentTopicId": "P2-Child1",
            "title": "demo title",
            "children": [
              {
                "id": "id2.1.1",
                "parentTopicId": "id2.1",
                "title": "demo titlename",
                "children": []
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

My desired output is:

```
{
 "rootId": "1",
  "items": {
    "1": {
      "id": "1",
      "children": [
        "P1",
        "P2"
      ],
      "hasChildren": true,
      "data": {
        "title": "root"
      }
    },
    "P1": {
      "id": "P1",
      "children": [
        "P1-Child1",
        "P1-Child2"
      ],
      "hasChildren": true,
      "data": {
        "title": "demo title a"
      }
    },
    "P2": {
      "id": "P2",
      "children": [
        "P2-Child1"
      ],
      "hasChildren": true,
      "data": {
        "title": "demo"
      }
    },
    "P1-Child1": {
      "id": "P1-Child1",
      "hasChildren": true,
      "children": [
        "id1.1.1"
      ],
      "data": {
        "title": "demo title"
      }
    },
    "P1-Child2": {
      "id": "P1-Child2",
      "children": [
        "id1.2"
      ],
      "hasChildren": true,
      "data": {
        "title": "demo titlename"
      }
    },
    "P2-Child1": {
      "id": "P2-Child1",
      "children": [
        "id2.1.1"
      ],
      "hasChildren": true,
      "data": {
        "title": "demo titlename"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am not sure how exactly to convert the input data to the format I require. Are there any suggestions on how I can flatten the json array?

I need to first filter the input array where parentTopicIds are null , so that I can place them inside items -> 1-> children arrray.  {"rootId": "1","items": {"1": {"id": "1","children": ["P1","P2"]}. This is pretty simple as I can just use filter function. But after this, how can I flatten the children of P1 and P2 ?

I found some very simple examples of flattening arrays but not to my requirement

One attempt to do it is

```
var outputData ={"rootId": "1","items": {"1": {"children":[]}}};

inputData.filter((item) => {
//first push all nodes whose parentTopicId is null
 if(item.parentTopicId == null) {
    outputData.items["1"]["children"].push(item.id);
    console.log(flatten(item.children)); // this does not provide the required result 
  }
});

function flatten(arr) {
    return arr.reduce((acc, cur) => acc.concat(Array.isArray(cur) ? flatten(cur) : cur), []);
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could flat by using a pattern an collect all nested object with that pattern.

This approach takes all children as well. If not wanted, you could add a check and omit the children without children.

```js
const
    flat = ({ id, title, children }) => ({
        [id]: {
            id,
            children: children.map(({ id }) => id),
            hasChildren: !!children.length,
            data: { title }
        },
        ...Object.assign({}, ...children.map(flat))
    }),
    data = { id: "null", title: "root", children: [{ id: "P1", parentTopicId: null, title: "demo title 1", children: [{ id: "P1-Child1", parentTopicId: "P1", title: "demo title a", children: [{ id: "id1.1", parentTopicId: "P1Child1", title: "some demo title b", children: [{ id: "id1.1.1", parentTopicId: "id1.1", title: "demo title", children: [] }] }] }, { id: "P1-Child2", parentTopicId: "P1", title: "some title 2", children: [{ id: "id1.2", parentTopicId: "P1-Child2", title: "demo titlename", children: [] }] }] }, { id: "P2", parentTopicId: null, title: "Example Title B", children: [{ id: "P2-Child1", parentTopicId: "P2", title: "example title b2", children: [{ id: "id2.1", parentTopicId: "P2-Child1", title: "demo title", children: [{ id: "id2.1.1", parentTopicId: "id2.1", title: "demo titlename", children: [] }] }] }] }] },
    result = flat(data);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use normalizr npm package.

```
import { normalize, schema } from 'normalizr';

const user = new schema.Entity('users');

const comment = new schema.Entity('comments', {
commenter: user  
});

const article = new schema.Entity('articles', {
author: user,
comments: [comment]
});

const normalizedData = normalize(originalData, article);
```

output:

```
{
result: "123",
 entities: {
  "articles": {
   "123": {
    id: "123",
    author: "1",
    title: "My awesome blog post",
    comments: [ "324" ]
  }
},
"users": {
  "1": { "id": "1", "name": "Paul" },
  "2": { "id": "2", "name": "Nicole" }
},
"comments": {
  "324": { id: "324", "commenter": "2" }
}
```

}
}

to learn more go through the documentation
https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr